# Modify php.ini on Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, laravel-5.6

Is there anyway to change the php.ini file on Laravel homestead? For instance, I want to have the short_open_tags set to On - however I can't see an easy way to do this - Apart from going into the php.ini file and changing it *every single time I boot homestead??*  I can't be doing that each time.

There has to be an easier way to simply override some settings in Laravel homestead.  What if I want larger file uploading, different time local etc?

How can I achieve this?  I've tried using the `ini_set()` command at the top of my php files, but that changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify `php.ini` to enable `<?=` on any version of PHP Homestead supports.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

```
5.4.0   The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.
```

If you *do* want to change ini settings you should do that in your `after.sh` script and use the style we use in settler via `sed` commands: https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh#L107-L125 Just make sure you're editing the right `php.ini`, there is one for each version of PHP in Homestead (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2) You'll also want to restart the FPM service after changing any values.

Comment: Sorry, Isnt `short_open_tags` referring to `<? echo 'hello';` (without the equals sign?) That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yep, you'll want to do this via `after.sh` Something along the lines of: `sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` Not sure if they all have that setting by default, you may need to append the line to the bottom of the file. but try this first.

Comment: Thank you - I put those lines into `after.sh` but my code (`<? echo "foobar"; ?>`) still wont run.  However it will run if I replaced the first tag with a long tag (`<?php`).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting.  If I take a look at `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini` in homestead ssh the `short_open_tag` is set to `On`.  However when I run `phpinfo()` it is displaying is `Off`