# PHP.ini showing different values to phpinfo() in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I;m trying to modify the PHP.ini file for Laravel homestead to enable `short_open_tags`.

Following [joepferguson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132364/1445985)'s advice, I've added the following lines into my after.sh file:

```
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
sudo sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

Now, when I SSH into my homestead server and run the following:

```
vagrant@homestead:/etc/php/7.1/fpm$ cat php.ini | grep short_
; short_open_tag
short_open_tag = On
```

It clearly shows that it is on.  However, they are still not working and when I run the following code:

It shows that it is indeed loading the same php.ini file: `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini`

But that shortopen tags is *still* set to Off, further down the file phpinfo():

[image]

If I run the command `php --ini` I get the following:

```
vagrant@homestead:/etc/php/7.1/fpm$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/90-blackfire.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/zray.ini
```

So homestead is loading a lot of ini files on top of php.ini, right? Except the website is using FPM, so I went to that directory and ran the following:

`vagrant@homestead:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d$ grep -R "short_open"`

But it returned nothing.  So there is no other INI file overwriting the first one, so why is short_open_tags still not working on the webpage??

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm after making your changes …?

Comment: Each time I restarted the entire homestead machine.

Comment: That's a good point though, maybe it's changing the php.ini but php needs to be restarted after that. How would I go about don't that?

Comment: Just remember that short tags are explicitly discouraged in the PHP manual. They will make your code non-portable; they will fail to be recognised by any IDE for syntax highlighting, and the syntax clashes with XML doctype declarations, so watch out if you are using XML anywhere in your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you are running

`sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart`

Or just restart the versions you're editing settings for.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.